# When choose Pick from gallery or camera options get error

Tags: android, android-studio

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.m3h.pmne, PID: 19352
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.m3h.pmne.ServerResponse.FormParentResponse)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1730)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1678)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:931)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:125)
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1532)
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1411)
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1396)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:58)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1699)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1605)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:931)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1596)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:931)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1596)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:3858)
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.m3h.pmne.ServerResponse.Data
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1725)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1678) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579) 
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:931) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:125) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedObject(Parcel.java:1532) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1411) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedList(Parcel.java:1396) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManagerState.java:58) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1699) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1605) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579) 
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:931) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1596) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579) 
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:931) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1596) 
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:891) 
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1579) 
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1233) 
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:3858) 
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.